# new component is not displaying

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, vue-component, laravel-5.7

m new to vue and after installing it in Laravel, I make a new component but its not showing in browser,and the browser gives warning in developers tools, in developers tools > console it shows:

```
  app.js:37960 [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: 
  template or render function not defined.
  found in

---> <TaskForm>
<Root>
warn @ app.js:37960
app.js:46384 You are running Vue in development mode.
Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html
```

is there any problem in code or if any solution to resolve this issue?

component:

```
   <template>

    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="card card-default">
         <div class="card-header">Task Form</div>

         <div class="card-body">
            <form action="./api/task" method="POST">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Task title" class="form-control">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
               <input type="submit" value="Add Task" class="btn btn-info">
              </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>

 </template>

<script>
  export default {
     mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')
    }
  }
</script>
```

app.js:

```
  require('./bootstrap');

 window.Vue = require('vue');

 Vue.component('example-component',  
    require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

  Vue.component("task-form", require('./components/TaskForm.vue'));

   const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app'
   });
```

this is app.blade.php: app.blade.php:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
     <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- CSRF Token -->
     <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

<!-- Fonts -->
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

 <!-- Styles -->
 <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light navbar-laravel">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                </ul>

                <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <!-- Authentication Links -->
                    @guest
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                        </li>
                        @if (Route::has('register'))
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                            </li>
                        @endif
                    @else
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>

                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                   onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                 document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                    {{ __('Logout') }}
                                </a>

                                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                    @csrf
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    @endguest
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <main class="py-4">
        @yield('content')
    </main>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the element with the ID of 'app'? There's also no closing tag for your template.

Comment: @Bryan I hv added the closing tag but where to put the ID of app can u plz tell me

Comment: You have to put the `#app` element where you want to mount your vue instance. In most cases it will be the first `div` element of the view returned by the server.

Comment: @toyi I have added id="app" at top div after template tag but nthing happens, I have made a component named task-form and wants to show it, m following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jkl2T5k6eAY&list=PLB4AdipoHpxZcaRs8RWpoywYf_JotqZnz&index=3

Comment: @programmer0001 You don't have to add it after the template tag. Take a look here, at 2:08 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ukZZyyfHCGc . You will see the `#app` element you need, line 24.

Comment: @toyi its already added  const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});  and where I hv to add this element, at which place?

Comment: @programmer0001 I don't think you understood what i meant. Can you edit your question with the code of the blade.php file where you include the js files, the css files etc..? If you do so, maybe i can tell you something more accurate. that's the file called `app.blade.php` inside the tutorial.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192840/discussion-between-programmer0001-and-toyi).